The content of element type "resultMap" must match "(constructor?,id*,result*,association*,collection*,discriminator?)
I have a MyBatis user result map xml defined like this:
<resultMap id="sysUser" type="com.gd.yzh.admin.dal.entity.user.AdminUserDo">
  <id property="id" column="id"/>
  <result property="username" column="username"/>
  <result property="password" column="password"/>
  <result property="nickname" column="nickname"/>
</resultMap>

everything works fine. But when I add the post_ids column defined like this:
<property="postIds" column="post_ids"
typeHandler="com.gd.frame.mybatis.core.type.JsonLongSetTypeHandler"/>

shows error:
The content of element type "resultMap" must match "(constructor?,id*,result*,association*,collection*,discriminator?)

I have already search from internet and told that the order of the xml resultMap should like:
1-constructor?,2-id*,3-result*,4-association*,5-collection*,6-discriminator

my xml define only contains id and result, obviously it orders by id and result. Am I missing something? This is the User postId defined like:
private set<Long> postIds;

and this is the JsonLongSetTypeHandler:
 public classJsonLongSetTypeHandler extends AbstractJsonTypeHandler<Object> {
    private static final TypeReference<Set<Long>> TYPE_REFERENCE = new TypeReference<Set<Long>>(){}，
    
    public JsonLongsetTypeHandler(){
    protected Object parse(string json){return JsonUtils.parseObject(ison, TYPE_REFERENCE);

    protected string toJson(object obj){
    return JsonUtils.toJsonstring(obj);
    }
   }

BTW, the postIds column store in database like this: [1].

The element with post_ids you posted does not even have an element name which should cause a different error. It means that you either 1) provided inaccurate information or 2) are looking at a wrong file.
In any case, that error is a pure XML syntax problem (i.e. it has nothing to do with MyBatis). There are many online XML validators that support DTD. You should check your XML mapper using those validators and see if they report the same problem.
